# Adding icon to toolbar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to add an icon to my toolbar using these two lines

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

The icon is added, however it's added in the center of the toolbar, how can I add it to the right corner of the toolbar for example?

This is my action_bar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_text"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why is the width wrap content?

Comment: @Remario the width of LinearLayout or the width of the TextView?

Comment: Linear, try match parent!

Comment: I tried, it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to set icon towards RIGHT in toolbar. An alternate way is to make use of Menu.

You can do the following

Create a Menu.xml in res/menu.xml  folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item"
          android:icon="@drawable/logo"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

In the Activity Implement the following method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.right_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Now with the above changes, you will see the icon on the right side of toolbar.

You can implement the tap by using the below method:-

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_item:   //this item has your app icon
                Toast.makeText(this,"Tapped on icon",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```